Making files inside any folder in my S3 bucket public
I am new with AWS and AWS S3 and I am not managing to see the files on certain folders in my bucket through their URLs.
My node.js application is uploading some static files to my folder bucket-name/./tmp/ but I can not access them through the URL. Besides this folder, I am also using several others.
Although I already have configured my Bucket Policy according to the instructions in this question (statement bellow), I am still not managing to see files that aren't in the root folder.
My bucket policy is:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*my-bucket-name*/*"
        }
    ]
}

Is there anyway to automatically allow all the files and folders in my bucket to be public?

Your bucket policy will permit anyone to retrieve objects from the bucket (assuming that you remove the * from *my-bucket-name*. Note that it won't allow listing of the bucket, so when you say "I am not managing to see the files" are you trying to download them or list them? Also, why do you have the /./ in your bucket-name/./tmp/ name? I wonder if that is causing a problem? Can you see the objects listed in the S3 console? If so, you can copy the URL from the console and attempt to access them in your browser. If that works, compare the URL with the one being used in node.

Hi @JohnRotenstein. Thanks for your answer.
I am using the static files in this bucket for showing them as pictures in my website. There is no confidential data in it, so it is perfectly fine if everyone can retrieve this files.
The /./tmp/ was indeed a mistake, I already corrected it. But I am still not managing to make everything there public.

As long as it is "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*" (with just the asterisk at the end), then your policy is correct. It will allow anyone to download an object from the bucket, but they need to know the exact name of the object. They can't list the bucket. Are you still having a problem? Can you describe what you're trying to do, and what error you receive?

It is working properly now. I deleted all the files in the folder I was using and for some reason now everything is public. Thanks again, @JohnRotenstein!

It worked properly when I started using tmp inside the root folder instead of putting it inside the . folder. (See the comments for more details)
